# React Bidirectional component communication

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, components

I am doing an app in react and the idea is to have a component lets call it component A which return function has :

```
                <div>
                            <div>
                                <ExtraComponent 1/>
                                <ExtraComponent 2/>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                  <B />
                            </div>
                </div>
```

Component B has one subcomponent called C that it toggles when clicked ( component C will only render if showProperty is true )

```
  B = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          showProperty: false
        }
      },

        handlerClick(e) {
        this.setState({
          showProperty: !this.state.showProperty
        });
        },

        render() {
            return (
                <div onClick= { this.handlerClick }>
                    <span>B</span>
            <C showProperty={this.state.showProperty} />
                </div>
            );
        }
    });
```

What I want to do is when component B toggles his subcomponent (C) I want him to communicate to component A ( its father ) that that has happened so it can toggle both ExtraComponents.

TLDR : I need a way for a component in react to communicate with its child and father at the same time.

Thanks in advance .

Greetings , John.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a callback from parent component into child component to get parent's state updated. thn you can pass the parent's state into other extra components.

```
 var A = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    toggleState: 'false'
  },

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <div>
                <ExtraComponent1 toggleState={this.state.toggleState}/>
                <ExtraComponent2 toggleState={this.state.toggleState}/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <B onToggle={this.onToggle.bind(this)}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  },

  onToggle(toggleState) {
    this.setState({ toggleState: toggleState });
  }
});

var B = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          showProperty: false
        }
      },

        handlerClick(e) {
        this.setState({
          showProperty: !this.state.showProperty
        });

        this.props.onToggle(this.state.showProperty);

        },

        render() {
            return (
                <div onClick= { this.handlerClick }>
                    <span>B</span>
            <C showProperty={this.state.showProperty} />
                </div>
            );
        }
    });
```